# IE9 Ajax Succeeds but no response body

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-9

I have a simple ajax request that works in all modern browsers but IE9 (of course). In IE9 the response comes back as 200, the success function fires, but there is no data returned.

Here is the js:

```
function getMapPins(section){
    $('.spinnerBG').fadeIn('fast');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ourprojects_ajax.html',
        data: {'map_section':section},
        cache:false,
        success: function(data){
            //alert(data);
            $('#mapPins').append(data);
            createPins(section);
        }
    });

}
```

And just to make sure it isn't the PHP:

```
<?php echo '<p>why won't this damn thing work in IE9</p>'; ?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Looking in IE's developer tools at the response body is completely empty and the response headers Content-Length is 0

Comment: I know you already have cache:false inside your ajax call.. but for giggles try this - before all your js code put this in there $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});

Answer (score 6):

It appears that there is a PARSE ERROR:

```
<?php echo '<p>why won't this damn thing work in IE9</p>'; ?>
```

should be:

```
<?php echo '<p>why won\'t this damn thing work in IE9</p>'; ?>
```

If you have your errors turned off then you won't get a response, as the page would be blank.

Comment: how to enable errors? when exceptions are thrown my page becomes blank   . is it a config in php.ini ?

Comment: it is. or you can add `error_reporting(E_ALL)` to the top of your php file

Comment: no dice. Previously the response was some more complex html. I have tried addslashes() and htmlspecialchars(). Even the simple string 'success' doesn't come back.

Comment: Are you sure that PHP is running on the server? Is your PHP setup to use .html as a file extension?

Comment: Yes, this works absolutely everywhere except IE9. I can visit the /ourprojects_ajax.html page and see the response, so I know the php script is working.

Comment: here is the actual live page: http://www.triglobalenergy.com/ourprojects.html The map has a clickable region that fires the ajax.